# Trouble getting fgetc working

Tags: c, fgetc

I am learning C and practicing by writing a small program that reads integers from a textfile and stores them into an array. However, the integers never get stored somehow and the array is empty.

```
 int readNumbers(int array[], char* fname) {                                                                                                                                                                                               
 78                                                                                                                                                                      
 79                                                                                                                                                                                             
 80     int numberRead = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 81     FILE* fp;                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 82     int ch;                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 83     int i = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 84                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 85                                                                                                                                                                                          
 86                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 87     fp = fopen(fname, "r");                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 88     // Test to see if the file was opened correctly                                                                                                                                                                                       
 89                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 90     if (fp == NULL) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 91             printf("Error opening file\n");                                                                                                                                                                                               
 92             return;                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 93     }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 94     // Now read until end of file                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 95                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 96     while (ch = fgetc(fp) != EOF && isdigit(ch)) {                                                                                                                                                                                        
 97             array[i++] = ch;                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 98     }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 99     if (ferror(fp)) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
100             return;                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
101     }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
102     // Close the file pointer                                                                                                                                                                                                             
103                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
104     fclose(fp);                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
105                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
106     // Return the number of items read                                                                                                                                                                                                    
107     return numberRead;                                                                                                                                                                          
108 }
```

The text file  would be something like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Thanks in advance.

I've updated the code. This almost works, but it interprets characters such as `55` as `5` and `5`. So my array would have two `5`'s.

```
 while ((ch =fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 97             if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n') {                                                                                                                                                                                                
 98                     array[counter] = ch - '0';                                                                                                                                                                                            
 99                     counter++;                                                                                                                                                                                                            
100                     numberRead++;                                                                                                                                                                                                         
101             }                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
102     }
```

Comment: change `ch = fgetc(fp) != EOF` to `(ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF`  . The comparison operator has higher precedence than the assignment.

Comment: Your function returns without closing the file in case of `ferror` which is a bit strange. Also it is illegal to have `return;` without an argument.

Comment: Note: Interesting that code is using `if (ferror(fp))`.  If true, `fp` is not closed.

Comment: I got this working. However, fgetc would interpret a number such as 55 into 5 and 5. I'll post the updated code for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on what Matt McNabb said in the comment, you can't have `return` without a value (unless it's inside a `void` function). Your `readNumbers()` function is declared to return `int` so **all** return paths must return an int. You may like to return -1 if there's a file error, since 0 is (kind of :) ) a valid number of chars to read.

Since there are spaces between the digits in your input file you will need to change the logic in your `while` loop.

`while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isdigit(ch))`

will fail as soon as it reads a non-digit char.

I should also mention that you are storing the numerical value of each char you read into your array, which might not be what you want. Eg, in ASCII a '0' char will have a numeric value of 48, '1' has a value of 49, etc.

PS. Make sure that the function that calls `readNumbers()` provides an array big enough to handle any possible result...

---

Try to avoid using `exit()` deep within your program, when practical, and just use it in `main()`. Also, rather than just killing your program stone dead with `exit()` it's **much** better to print some kind of error message first (usually to stderr), and *then* die gracefully. As for creating suitable error messages, check out the `<stdio.h>` function `perror()`, and take a look at `<errno.h>`.

You can either print the error message in `readNumbers()` and return -1, and then let the calling function (eg `main()`) decide if the error's so bad that the program should die. Or let the calling function handle the printing of the error message, too.

Comment: Awesome, how about using exit(0) in place of return -1?

Answer (score 1):

you should us the parentheses here `while (ch = fgetc(fp) != EOF && isdigit(ch))` , it should be `while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isdigit(ch))` otherwise you will store in `ch` the value of `fgetc(fp) != EOF` which is eather 1 or 0 ( TRUE or FALSE)

Answer (score 1):

```
// this following code modification will handle your most recent question

int value = 0; // place to accumulate numbers
int inNumber = 0; // to avoid spurious input in array[]

// note: the following expects that 'ch' is defined as an integer
while ((ch =fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') // only process numeric characters
    {
        value *= 10;
        value += (ch - 0x30); // convert alpha to binary 
        inNumber = 1;
    }
    else
    { // break between numbers
        if( 1 == inNumber )
        {
            array[counter] = value;
            counter++;
            numberRead++;
            value = 0; // reset for next number
            inNumber = 0;
        }
    }
}
```